# Multiple instances of one form_for on a single page? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Thank you in advance,

I have a simple Document model and form_for to create a new document.

All I would like to do is have multiple - say 3 - forms on one page which will create three separate model instances. **Either seperate 'submit' buttons or one main one**

**new.html.erb:**

```
  <% 3.times do %>
    <%= render 'documents/new_document_form' %>
  <% end %>
```

**_new_document_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @document do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>

    <%= f.file_field :document_file %>

    <%= f.submit "Save Changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
```

**documents_controller.rb**

```
  def new
    @document = current_account.documents.build if signed_in?
  end

 def create
    @document = current_account.documents.build(params[:document])
    if @document.save
      flash[:success] = "Successful document upload!"
      redirect_to documents_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Please try again"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

I could use some help understanding:

- how to create multiple unique instances of the forms
- pass the input successfully to the **controller**
- any more info!